# WebIOPi can't be downloaded from The Pi Store

Tags: pi-store, webiopi

I have Raspberry Pi 2 Model B v1.1. (Noobs 1.4.1 Raspbian loaded)

On The Pi Store, I registered myself then tried to download WebIOPi. But after the clicking on download button, it said that wait for 5 seconds for PayPal page to load. But, nothing responsed to me to download WebIOPi. So, download didn't start. By the way, why a free package as WebIOPi needs Paypal page to pay something? It is free of charge as mentioned on the store.

Comment: I'd get it from a different source.  Google webiopi.  Isn't webIOPi free?

Comment: Don't forget that the Pi store is dead. The company behind it went bust and the foundation cites tax reasons for not continuing with it.

Answer (score 1):

From the Raspberry Pi webpage you can download the OS you want to install on your SD, but to get the WebIOPi you need to go the [WebIOPi downloads](http://webiopi.trouch.com/DOWNLOADS.html) page.

It is completely free and the last version of course.

Comment: @Bay this answer helped you? if it did, I think you should mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are using a **Raspberry Pi 2 Model B** you might want to check out this Patch Version for overcoming compatibility issues

[Patch for RPi2 WebIOPi](https://github.com/doublebind/raspi)

It works like charm for me.